# MVC 4 Application, Windows Authentication, and Custom roles stored in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

Good morning everyone,

I have the following requirement for my MVC 4 Application.

1. Authentication using windows credentials (automatic).
2. Once authenticated specific pages/views/controllers within the app are restricted based upon a role that is defined in a set of database tables.

EDIT

Here is what i have tried so far:

1. Set my MVC application to use Windows Authentication
2. Put this in my Global.asax file

   if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
   {
   string[] roles = { "testmyrole" };
   GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, roles);
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
   bool test = User.IsInRole("testmyrole");
   }

But the HttpContext.Current.User is always null...

The string[] roles will eventually be populated by calling the database ... the hard code is just for testing right now.

Any ideas of where i can put the above piece of code in my MVC app so that no matter what View is called this code gets run so i can populate the roles and then use the following code in my other controllers

```
[Authorize(Roles ="testmyrole")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
... do other fun stuff here
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Corey

Comment: Hello...Just some friendly advice. You'll struggle to get a "detailed" solution from anyone unless you attempt something 1st.

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have found a solution to my problem.

So here is what i did:

1. Modified my viewStart.CSHTML file as follows:

@using SMTRApp.Business;

@using System.Security.Principal;

@using System.Threading;

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    string[] roles = BusinessLayer.BLGetUserRoles(User.Identity.Name).ToArray();
    GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, roles);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

I then was able to put the following code at the beginning of my controllers to implement SQL role based security:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Accounting, Analyst, ETL")]
```

Is there a better approach than this to implement role based security no matter how the view is invoked?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Corey